# How to display PHP if or else in customizable modal after form submit

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, forms

I have a working php contact form on a one page site. When user clicks submit, they are taken to a separate PHP page that displays IF statement that they filled the form correctly, OR, the page displays with the PHP ELSE statement if they filled it out wrong. What I want to do is instead of opening the PHP page, I would rather the user see a modal that I may style to fit my site look/feel, which displays the IF or ELSE statements. These are the statements in my PHP file:

```
function died($error) {
// your error code can go here 
echo "We are very sorry, but there were error(s) found with the form you submitted. "; 
echo "These errors appear below.<br /><br />"; 
echo $error."<br /><br />"; 
echo "Please go back and fix these errors.<br /><br />";
die();
}

// Validate expected data exists
if(!isset($_POST['visitorname']) || !isset($_POST['company_name']) 
|| !isset($_POST['email']) || !isset($_POST['phone']) || !isset($_POST['subject'])  
||!isset($_POST['comments'])) {
died('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.');
}

$visitorname = $_POST['visitorname']; // required 
$company_name = $_POST['company_name']; // not required 
$email_from = $_POST['email']; // required 
$phone = $_POST['phone']; // not required
$subject = $_POST['subject']; // required 
$comments = $_POST['comments']; // required 
$error_message = ""; 
$email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/'; 
if(!preg_match($email_exp,$email_from)) {
$error_message .= 'The Email Address you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
} 
$string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/"; 
if(!preg_match($string_exp,$visitorname)) {
$error_message .= 'The Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
}
$string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/"; 
if(!preg_match($string_exp,$subject)) {
$error_message .= 'The subject you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
}
if(strlen($comments) < 2) {
$error_message .= 'The message you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
}
if(strlen($error_message) > 0) {
died($error_message);
}
$email_message = "Form details below.\n\n";
function clean_string($string) {
$bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
}
$email_message .= "Name: ".clean_string($visitorname)."\n";
$email_message .= "Company: ".clean_string($company_name)."\n"; 
$email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($email_from)."\n";
$email_message .= "Phone: ".clean_string($phone)."\n";
$email_message .= "Subject: ".clean_string($subject)."\n";
$email_message .= "Message: ".clean_string($comments)."\n";

// This section creates the email headers
$auth = array('host' => $host, 'auth' => true, 'username' => $username, 'password' 
=>  $password);
$headers = array('From' => $from_address, 'To' => $email_to, 'Subject' 
=>   $email_subject, 'Reply-To' => $reply_to);

// This section send the email
$smtp = Mail::factory('smtp', $auth);
$mail = $smtp->send($email_to, $headers, $email_message);

if (PEAR::isError($mail)) {?>
<!-- include your own failure message html here -->
Unfortunately, the message could not be sent at this time. Please try again later.


<!-- <?php echo("<p>". $mail->getMessage()."</p>"); ?> -->

<?php } else { ?>


Thank you for contacting me. I will respond as soon as possible.

<?php } } ?>
```

The following Jquery/Ajax is close to what I want because I can submit the form without leaving the page, but I don't know how to get the PHP if/else statements to appear in the alert box. I also don't like the appearance of the alert box as I can't style it.

```
$ (function() {

$('form.contactform').on('submit',function(){

var element=$(this),
url=element.attr('action'),
type=element.attr('method'),
data={};

element.find('[name]').each(function(index,value){
var element=$(this),
name=element.attr('name');
value=element.val();

data[name]=value;
});

$.ajax({
url:url,
type:type,
data:data,
success:function(response){
console.log(response);
// add your thank you pop up here
alert("Need to call PHP IF/ELSE here somehow.");
}
});
return false;
});
```

I want to note that I am not too handy with Jquery/Ajax/PHP. I got the second bit of code from another user on here that helped me. Thanks.

Comment: Trying to display `IF THEN ELSE` statement or using it?

Answer (score 0):

You can create an empty div anywhere on your html page and have the contents filled by jquery when the ajax call returns.

Somewhere on your page:

```
<div id="contactresponse">
</div>
```

Then change the line that contains your alert call to:

```
$("#contactresponse").text(response.responseText);
```

Do you happen to use jQuery UI? If you do, you could turn that div into a popup by adding the line:

```
$("#contactresponse").dialog();
```

Comment: What I am looking to do is grab the if statement from the php code and have it show in the alert box if the user filled the form out incorrectly. Or display the else statement if the user sent the form successfully.

Comment: To show it in the default alert box, changing `alert("Thank you for ...");` to `alert(response.responseText);` should be enough. If you want a customized/stylable popup, you will have to create one with html/javascript. The method I described in my comment above is one way of doing that.

Comment: What I am trying to do is reference either of these two statements from the php code. It's important for the form to send a message whether or not it was filled out incorrectly. Please see the php lines of code in the first part of my question

Comment: I edited my question to show the entire php code, except for info on my web mail account. I need to show the error message(s), or success message in a popup. Sorry if I have not been clear. Help is appreciated.